# How to integrate Kaleo workflow in custom Portlet?

Tags: workflow, liferay, liferay-6

I have created one custom portlet in which i am having one Button named **INITIATE(This should work as *Submit for Publication* as it is in the case of Web Content)**. What i want is that on click of this button my workflow should be initiated. I have done this kind of thing in Web Content Portlet. But I want to to that what code should i write on the Click of INITIATE button so my workflow starts? Please kindly help me if anyone has any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the liferay official documentation?

Kaleo workflow:
http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/workflow-with-kal-2

Add workflow to custom entity
http://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/how-to-add-workflow-capabilities-on-knowledge-base-articles-or-any-custom-assets-in-plugins

You should call

And what problem do you have?? You should call

```
 WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance(
        user.getCompanyId(), groupId, userId, KBArticle.class.getName(),
        resourcePrimKey, kbArticle, serviceContext);
```

You can see the example in http://svn.liferay.com/repos/public/plugins/trunk/portlets/knowledge-base-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/liferay/knowledgebase/service/impl/KBArticleLocalServiceImpl.java (knowledge base is linked from the second article..)

(username guest, password guest)

Comment: thanks for your reply but i have already gone through this links. Its still not working....

Comment: The links above don't work anymore. The first one is broken and the second one requires auth.

Comment: Yeah, the answer is more than one year old. No reason to downvote it. Added the obvious auth info.

Comment: Second link is broken, seems like there is no jonas.yuan's blog on liferay.com anymore.

Comment: I downvoted because the answer is rather pointless without working links. It's not a comment on your knowledge or ability!

Comment: Fixed second link for anyone who is still interested.